# Solving $\lfloor 2022 x \rfloor+\{2023 x\}=2023$

Tags: solution-verification, fractional-part

*question*

Solve in the set of real numbers the equation $\lfloor 2022 x \rfloor+\{2023 x\}=2023$, where (where $\lfloor a\rfloor$ and $\{a\}$ represent the whole part, respectively the fractional part of the real number $a$)

*my idea*

Can you tell me if my idea is right or wrong? If so, can you tell me how i should solve this problem.

First of all i wrote $\lfloor 2022 x\rfloor +\{2023 x\}=2023$ as  $2022x-\{2022 x\}+\{2023 x\}=2023$ which means that $\{2023 x\}-\{2022 x\}=2023-2022x$

We know that  $-1<{2023 x}-{2022 x}<1$ which means that $-1<2023-2022 x<1$

From this we get that $1<x<\frac{2024}{2022}$

Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Hard to read what you have written since $\{\}$ is missing.

Comment: @geetha290krm sorry, i will edit it!

Comment: You need to write \{ to make the symbol show.

Comment: To make the curly brackets render properly you need to add backslashes, as in \{ ...\}

Comment: I edited your post, to add the curly brackets.  Note:  I also changed your notation for the floor to the, more standard, $\lfloor x \rfloor$.  Feel free to change it back if you prefer the older style notation.  You can click on edit to see the syntax I used to make the changes.

Comment: @lulu Thank you so muchh!

Comment: the answer is $\frac{2025}{2023} = 1.000988630746$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your considerations are correct, but incomplete. Relying on rote algebraic manipulations is not going to be particularly useful here. Instead, start by thinking about what obvious properties the two summands have:

1. $\lfloor 2022x\rfloor$ is a natural number.
2. $\{2023x\}$ is in the half-open interval $[0,1)$.
3. $\{2023x\} = 2023 - \lfloor 2022x\rfloor$ is a natural number.

The combination of 2 and 3 tells us that $\{2023x\} = 0$, i.e. that $2023x$ is itself a natural number, and that $\lfloor 2022x\rfloor = 2023$.

Since $2023x \in \mathbb{N}$, we know that $x = \frac{n}{2023}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The remaining requirement is that $\lfloor \frac{2022n}{2023}\rfloor = 2023$. Clearly, this requires $n > 2023$. We can then test the following values by numerical calculation. We find that $2024$ is still a little too small. Taking $n = 2025$ works. And then $2026$ is already too large.

Thus, the unique solution to $\lceil 2022x\rceil + \{2023x\} = 2023$ is $x = \frac{2025}{2023}$.

Comment: Tahnk you so much for your idea, but can you tell me how do i continue the problem? Thank you again?